# ¿Cómo mostrar un página web dentro de Adobe Flash As3?

Tags: adobe-flash

Como dice el título, me gustaria saber cómo mostrar una url de una página web dentro de un textarea o algo parecido en un proyecto de adobe flash.

He buscado casi todo internet por esto y no he encontrado nada al respecto, ¿Alguien sabe algo sobre esto?

Muchas gracias de ante mano

Por ejemplo algo parecido a esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver c++?

Comment: no encontre etiquetas para action script o flash :s

Comment: No tendrias que usar un iframe?

Comment: Eso no implica que coloque otras etiquetas, a los que queremos ayudarte nos sirve para filtrar las preguntas. Y en mi caso yo no trabajo con web pero si con C++, con esa ligereza me haces perder el tiempo.

Comment: en el caso de HTML si seria un iframe pero en flash no hay iframes que yo sepa por el momento solo he visto los textarea pero son para mostrar un documento de texto local, y lo que ando buscando es alguna forma de introducir una URL de una pagina web (X) al documento flash por medio de algo parecido a un iframe.